# Bind parameters to partial SQL statement

Tags: php, pdo, dynamic-sql

I am dealing with an old PHP application and have been tasked with making sure all areas used prepared statements. Currently it uses sprintf to build most of the query before executing.

Below is some example code of the current implementation:

```
$queryString = "SELECT count(user.uid) as count
              FROM user
              LEFT JOIN voucher
                ON user.voucher_uid = voucher.uid
              LEFT JOIN affiliation
                ON voucher.uid = affiliation.voucher_uid
                  @affiliation
              LEFT JOIN account
                ON affiliation.account_uid = account.uid
              WHERE affiliation.account_uid IN (@accounts)
                @active
                @search
                @template
                @onlyown
                AND voucher.template NOT LIKE 'api_%'
                AND user.role != 'superadmin'";
$sql = replace_tokens(
  $queryString,
  array(
    'accounts' => implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($accounts), '?')),
    'template' => $template,
    'search' => $search,
    'onlyown' => $onlyown,
    'affiliation' => $affiliation,
    'active' => $active
  )
);

return array_get(self::queryFetchOne($sql, $accounts), 'count', 0);
```

The `replace_tokens` function replaces the "variables" declared with @ in front of them with sql. Here is an example of how the `@search` variable is built.

```
if (is_string($search) && !empty($search)) {
  $search = sprintf('AND (voucher.code LIKE "%%%s%%" OR user.email LIKE "%%%s%%" OR user.salutation LIKE "%%%s%%")', $search, $search, $search);
} else {
  $search = '';
}
```

Now, I would like to solve the search problem by changing `%%%s%%` to `:search` and simply using a named parameter. However, the `$accounts` variable is an array of account names and uses question mark parameters for the in statement.

The answer to my questions is probably no, but I would like to solve this without having to only use question mark parameters which would require me to keep track of the order that I keep for all parameters when building the array.

**Are there any good ways to bind parameters to a partial statement or get around the issue of using lots of question mark parameters that I have described above?**

Comment: Nope it is not possible. You can keep with the current approach though, just make sure that `"%%%s%%"` (quotes included) is replaced with `$pdo->quote($variable)` result. Or you can continue your hassle with parameters but in this case you''l have to collect all variables into array for the further execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by building up two variables: one is the query string, and the other is a hash array of query parameters.

```
if (is_string($search) && !empty($search)) {
  $search = 'AND (voucher.code LIKE :code OR user.email LIKE :email OR user.salutation LIKE :salutation)';
  $params['code'] = "%%$search%%";
  $params['email'] = "%%$search%%";
  $params['salutation'] = "%%$search%%";
} else {
  $search = '';
}
```

By the time you're done with all the conditional code, you have a hash array of query parameters that you can pass to PDO `execute()`.

But you must make sure that all your named parameters are unique. If you use the same names in different conditional search terms, chaos will ensue. In that case, positional parameters have an advantage.

Comment: The variable ´$accounts´ might have around 20 variables on average but could have many more, thousands possibly. You would recommend generating a named parameter for each value in the array using a loop?

Comment: That's also a case where positional parameters have an advantage. It's easy to use `array_fill()` for a bunch of `?`, but a bit more work to make a series of named parameters. Probably need `array_map()`. PHP anonymous function syntax always makes me hate the language. :-P

Comment: @MarkusTenghamn it is quite possible with named placeholders as well, check [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in). However, you must realize that you are already using placeholders, your "%%%s%%" is as good as a native `?`

Answer (score 0):

This is an error of engineering.

My recommendation; an array with variables that is respective to the parameters.
For instance

Let `$sql1 = "select * from Apples where a=? and b=?"`

And `$sql2 = " or c=?;"`

Both generated from functions `gen_sql1()` and `gen_sql2()`.

Simply have `gen_sql1` return the first half of the array: `1, 2`. Have `gen_sql2` return the second half: `3`.

At the end, combine the arrays and you have an array and plug them into the "?" params in respective order:

`$fullsql = "select * from Apples where a=1 and b=2 or c=3"`